# Eclipse console shows a red text run-time error but doesn't have enough error information. How do I find this error?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, runtime-error

I'm working on a large ActionScript 3.0 project in Eclipse(Flash-builder 4.5) where I input a file via drag and drop into the program window. I don't know much about the codebase since I've come into it recently. Usually, while debugging and something gets thrown, it has a stack trace and more information on the error(in red text on the console). This time, however, the program continues to run and doesn't respond to my drag and drop with anything but one line of red text with some error information.

How can I pinpoint this problem so I can find out what's going wrong? The one line is just the input file I'm trying to run the program on. I've tried to step through earlier in the code when it's still working, but there must be other events being dispatched that I don't know about. I've also put traces in all the catch brackets to make sure I see if anything is thrown.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might want to provide the stack trace and error information

Comment: There is no stack trace because the program continues to run. Somewhere there's an error that occurs and all it says on the console in red is "app:/buttons.swf" which is a file I successfully load up before. I've checked to make sure it has the right path and don't know how to relate that to what's going wrong.